# Estimating singular values of integral operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, eigenvalues, integral-transforms, integral-operators

I would like to estimate the singular values of certain trace class integral operators. For the sake of concreteness, consider on $L^2({\mathbb R},dx)$ the integral operator $$(Tf)(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}dy\,\frac{w(x)}{x-y+ik}\,f(y),$$ where $k>0$ is a parameter and $w$ a fixed Schwartz class function, e.g. $w(x)=\exp(-s\,x^2)$ for some $s>0$.

This is a trace class operator, and one can estimate its trace norm by splitting into a product of two Hilbert Schmidt operators. However, how can I estimate the individual singular values $\mu_n(T)$ of $T$? More specifically, is there a known test for (strechted) exponential decay of singular values, i.e. $\mu_n(T)\leq C\,\exp(-a\,n^\alpha)$ for suitable constants $C,a,\alpha>0$?